# Python QTreeWidget setting root element

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I am working on python plugins.I used PYQT4 designer for the forms.
I am listing my query result into **QTreeWidget** as shown below:

```
     items = []
     for row in c.fetchall():

          item = QTreeWidgetItem()
          item.setText(0,unicode (row[0]))
          items.append(item)

 self.treeWidget.insertTopLevelItems(0, items)
```

Items are listed perfectly into the QTreeWidget.

[image]

But i wanted to make some items as parent like:
EX:

ACO_010

```
-2
-1
-7 and so on...
```

How do i set any item as **parent** (root) of other items.???
I tried

```
self.treeWidget.__init__ (self,valestimate,items, int type = self.treeWidget.Type)
```

but no success.How do i set parent in **QTreeWidget**??.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentItem.addChild(childItem)

(see the [QTreeWidgetItem documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitem.html#addChild))